# why do most file formats define a start of file marker?

Tags: file-format

For instance jpeg (JFIF) has a SOI (start of image) marker. One can argue that it can be used to identify the type of file, but I'm looking for more sound reason with supporting examples.

Comment: Are you sure that "most" formats have a start market? How did you count them?

Comment: If it's true at all it's because the designers made that decision separately in each case, for reasons which may have been different in each case, and which may be lost in the mists of time. The connection with networking and operating systems escapes me completely.

Comment: This seems to be very similar to [Why do file formats have magic numbers?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3841533/62576) based on the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are often referred to as "signature bytes" and their primary  purpose is simply to aide in validating the file. Some file types contain additional signature bytes elsewhere in the file (ie: BMP format), and some contain none at all. The latter kind still generally provide some other means to validate the file using a variety of techniques, such as checksums, stored file size and the like.